# iOS - Remove consent dialog 3rd party authentication with auth0

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, auth0, google-signin

I am trying to use facebook third-party login with Auth0 in my app.
Everytime I am trying to initiate a log in from the app and when I want it to open up the facebook app for login it first displays a dialog asking for user consent:

" **[App] wants to log in with "auth0.com"** *This allows the app and website to share information about you* "

I would like to remove this dialog completely since the user consent page is also displayed in the facebook app when asking for consent. I have the setting in auth0 for "Allow skipping user consent" on for the API in the dashboard.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if we cant remove it as states in https://community.auth0.com/questions/12941/ios-swift-remove-consent-dialog-social-login-with. Can we modify it?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way of having the alert message removed, we are experiencing the same issue on our apps.

I along with many others have filed a bug regarding this to Apple, asking them to show it only once or not at all. The end of this GitHub thread discusses the alert.

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/120

Answer (score 1):

You can use the legacy solution.

```
Auth0.webAuth().useLegacyAuthentication()
```

It works, but I would not recommend it going forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you use AppAuth:

Go to OIDExternalUserAgentIOS > line 117 after @available(iOS 13.0, *)
write this line :
`authenticationVC.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true`